# Satellite TV Dish antenna

Tags: antenna

Is there any fixed relation among the operating frequency, diameter of dish-antenna parabolic reflector and the wave-guide (LNB) dimension? What are the best design principles of such antenna? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There are literally books discussing each of your main points. This question is too broad, and I would narrow it down to avoid getting it closed.

Answer (score 2):

I just happen to be working on my Antennas homework so I have the book in front of me,

From Kraus Antennas(1950)

for Large Circular Apertures wit Uniform Illumination

[directivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directivity)  = 4Pi Area/Wavelength^2

This says that as you make dish larger the beam becomes more focused. Also that the size of the dish is proportional frequency of operation.

As Matt Young says there are whole chapters in books that cover these types of antennas I would highly recommend looking through one.

Comment: Thanx for your insight! I'm referring to the same book by J. D. Kraus. Found really interesting text on offset feed parabolic and spiral antennas. Seem I've a lot of work to do!